# Weighted undirected graphs, complex Laplacian, complex eigenvalues & spectral clusering

Tags: complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

I am rather puzzled and confused, I have been trying to get a clear understanding of how would spectral clustering work for an undirected weighted graph, I have used the normalized Laplacian, but I always get complex not strictly positive eigenvalues, all the resources I am finding build on the results that the Laplacian is real symmetric positive semi-definite matrix, hence real non-negative eigenvalues. Any guidance is greatly appreciated, specially in the answer to the question if I take the norm of the normalized Laplacian would spectral clustering algorithms be still valid with same results.

Comment: It would help if you could give a smallish example.  The [symmetric normalized Laplacian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix#Symmetric_normalized_Laplacian) $D^{-1/2} L D^{-1/2}$ is symmetric, and so should have real eigenvalues (even if we are generalizing a bit to weighted graphs).